# how do you report someone abusing power on this site?

Tags: support, moderation

it seems as if a member of this website (which is not a community) is abusing his power. how do i bring it to the attention of the site directors to potentially ask them to suspend his privileges?

Comment: By "someone" I assume you mean a moderator, since you said abusing "power".

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about me closing your question, [Why might having a pet be inappropriate for an Upasika visiting a monastery?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/why-might-having-a-pet-be-inappropriate-for-an-upasika-visiting-a-monastery) as "primarily opinion-based", and then closing its exact duplicate (now deleted by you), [Why might having a service animal be inappropriate for upasika training?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/why-might-having-a-service-animal-be-inappropriate-for-upasika-training) which you posted several hours later.

A closed question can be reopened by another moderator or the community cast of 5 votes. Please do not try to circumvent the moderation system by double-posting questions.

Comment: my question was not opinion based. it was a valid question. perhaps you should meditate on you animosity toward the facts and perhaps it would benefit you to consider why you are assuming so much. who are you anyway?... what credentials justify your desicion making abilities on buddhist subject matter?

Comment: and another moderator... Yuttadhammo admonished you for closing it. Your aversion to it becoming public has nothing to do with my question and therefore gives strength to the theory of power abuse. Whats your problem dude?

Comment: "primarily opinion-based" means that "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." As an elected moderator I'm acting on behalf of community, keeping this site clean of garbage questions. My whiskers, paws, and tail -- these are my credentials :)

Comment: that is entirely presumptive of answers that have not been given. You are assuming you know things you do not know... this is delusion. elected officials have proven over time that the election process is flawed. neither do you had whiskers paws or a tail. it seems you are the one giving all the opinions.

Comment: @david... perhaps judging andrei isnt the most skillful way to help him see the error of his ways or to practice for your own enlightenment. though i would tend to agree that he is not a valid choice for moderation!

Comment: @ANonimous said "that is entirely presumptive of answers that have not been given" I'm sorry, but this is how SE sites work. If question looks inappropriate, it can be closed before it receives any answers. Ideally, questions should be closed through community voting, but  because our community is still too weak to gather 5 votes, moderators have to step in.

Comment: @ANonimous just for the record, I wasn't admonishing Andrei, I was disagreeing with him. I hope it is okay for moderators to disagree. I respect his decision and will wait for the community to decide on the validity of the question.